# Using parameter substitution on a Bash array

Tags: bash, shell-script, array, variable-substitution, parameter

I have file.txt that I need to read into a Bash array.  Then I need to remove spaces, double quotes and *all but the first comma in every entry*.  Here's how far I've gotten:

```
$ cat file.txt
10,this
2 0 , i s
30,"all"
40,I
50,n,e,e,d,2
60",s e,e"

$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
readarray -t ARRAY<$1
ARRAY=( "${ARRAY[@]// /}" )
ARRAY=( "${ARRAY[@]//\"/}" )
for ELEMENT in "${ARRAY[@]}";do
    echo "|ELEMENT|$ELEMENT|"
done

$ ./script.sh file.txt
|ELEMENT|10,this|
|ELEMENT|20,is|
|ELEMENT|30,all|
|ELEMENT|40,I|
|ELEMENT|50,n,e,e,d,2|
|ELEMENT|60,se,e|
```

Which works great except for the comma situation.  I'm aware that there are multiple ways to skin this cat, but due to the larger script this is a part of, I'd really like to use parameter substitution to get to here:

```
|ELEMENT|10,this|
|ELEMENT|20,is|
|ELEMENT|30,all|
|ELEMENT|40,I|
|ELEMENT|50,need2|
|ELEMENT|60,see|
```

Is this possible via parameter substitution?

Comment: Is there any reason you need to keep the text in an array, and why you can't let e.g. `awk` or `sed` do the processing of the data?

Comment: @Jeff -- Looping over the array will be a nightmare to implement in the larger script I'm working on.

Comment: @JonRed I don't know what you are doing, so it's entirely possible that you may not have a choice in the matter, but generally, when you find yourself doing such complex string acrobatics in the shell, that's a very good indication that you should be using an actual programming language. The shell is not designed as a programming language, and while it can be used as one, it really isn't a good idea for more complex things. I strongly urge you to consider switching to perl or python or any other scripting language.

Comment: @terdon It's funny, I just got done saying almost the exact same thing to my colleague before I read this post. I basically said this is the final version of this script and that any further requirements will necessitate re-writing in Perl. So yeah, I definitely agree

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would remove what you need to remove using `sed` *before* loading into the array (also note the lower case variable names, in general it is best to avoid capitalized variables in shell scripts):

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray -t array< <(sed 's/"//g; s/  *//g; s/,/"/; s/,//g; s/"/,/' "$1")
for element in "${array[@]}";do
    echo "|ELEMENT|$element|"
done
```

This produces the following output on your example file:

```
$ foo.sh file 
|ELEMENT|10,this|
|ELEMENT|20,is|
|ELEMENT|30,all|
|ELEMENT|40,I|
|ELEMENT|50,need2|
|ELEMENT|60,see|
```

---

If you really must use parameter substitution, try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray -t array< "$1"
array=( "${array[@]// /}" )
array=( "${array[@]//\"/}" )
array=( "${array[@]/,/\"}" )
array=( "${array[@]//,/}" )
array=( "${array[@]/\"/,}" )

for element in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "|ELEMENT|$element|"
done
```

Comment: @JonRed I added a version with parameter substitution but it's complex, cumbersome and ugly. Doing this sort of thing in the shell is very rarely a good idea.

Comment: Note that if you've removed both spaces and double quotes, these characters becoma available to use instead of your `RANDOMTEXTTHATWILLNEVERBEINTHEFILE`.

Comment: @Kusalananda yeah, I just read your answer. Should have thought of that! Thanks :)

Comment: Directly answers the question, illustrates why my preferred solution isn't ideal, and provides the most viable alternative.  You win, best answer.

Answer (score 11):

As far as I can see, there's no need to read it into a `bash` array to create that output:

```
$ sed 's/[ "]//g; s/,/ /; s/,//g; s/ /,/; s/.*/|ELEMENT|&|/' <file
|ELEMENT|10,this|
|ELEMENT|20,is|
|ELEMENT|30,all|
|ELEMENT|40,I|
|ELEMENT|50,need2|
|ELEMENT|60,see|
```

The `sed` expression deletes spaces and double quotes, replaces the first comma with a space (there are no other spaces in the string at this point), deletes all other commas, restores the first comma, and the prepends and appends the extra data.

Alternatively, with GNU `sed`:

```
sed 's/[ "]//g; s/,//2g; s/.*/|ELEMENT|&|/' <file
```

(standard `sed` does not support the combination of `2` and `g` as flags to the `s` command).

Comment: with GNU sed, you can use `'s/,//2g` to remove commas, *starting with the 2nd*

Comment: And, the last 2 s/// commands can be `s/.*/|ELEMENT|&|/` but that may be more effort for sed.

Comment: @glennjackman Possibly, but it looks rather neat.

Comment: Yeah, this is part of a larger script.  The array is necessary, not just for the output.  Hence my interest in parameter substitution.  I could loop over the array with this but that will be a nightmare to implement.  Terndon provided a loop-free solution using sed that I'll likely fall back on if parameter substitution is a no-go.

Comment: If I wasn't tied to using an array, however, this would be best solution.

Comment: For standard sed and `2` and `g` modifiers, the GNU sed manual says: "the POSIX standard *does not specify* what should happen when you mix the g and number modifiers, and currently there is no widely agreed upon meaning across sed implementations." (my emphasis)

Comment: @glennjackman The POSIX spec. has "the results are unspecified." for mixing `g` with a number.

Comment: Nevertheless, without knowing all of the OP's constraints, this is my favourite solution.

Comment: @glennjackman It's convenient. I'd agree with that.

Answer (score 9):

```
ELEMENT='50,n,e,e,d,2'
IFS=, read -r first rest <<<"$ELEMENT"
printf "%s,%s\n" "$first" "${rest//,/}"
```

```
50,need2
```

Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names. You'll eventually collide with a crucial "system" variable like PATH and break your code.

Comment: Not parameter substitution.  BUT, I was unaware that ALLCAPS variable names was a bad habit in Bash.  You make a good point, one that a cursory googling definitely confirms.  Thank you for improving my style! :)

Comment: I've answer questions where the person wrote `PATH=something; ls $PATH` and then wondered about the `ls: command not found` error.

Comment: There are nearly a hundred built-in variables that are named in all caps (click through [this man page link](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Variables.html#Shell-Variables)) to see...

Answer (score 8):

[This is essentially a more fully developed version of [glenn jackmann's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/508782/65304)]

Building an associative array from the stripped key and value, using the first comma as separator:

```
declare -A arr
while IFS=, read -r k v; do arr["${k//[ \"]}"]="${v//[ ,\"]}"; done < file.txt
for k in "${!arr[@]}"; do 
  printf '|ELEMENT|%s,%s|\n' "$k" "${arr[$k]}"
done
|ELEMENT|20,is|
|ELEMENT|10,this|
|ELEMENT|50,need2|
|ELEMENT|40,I|
|ELEMENT|60,see|
|ELEMENT|30,all|
```

Answer (score 6):

You could loop over the array and use an intermediate variable:

```
for((i=0; i < "${#ARRAY[@]}"; i++))
do
  rest="${ARRAY[i]#*,}"
  ARRAY[i]="${ARRAY[i]%%,*}","${rest//,/}"
done
```

This assigns to `rest` the portion after the first comma; we then concatenate three pieces back into the original variable:

- the portion before the first comma
- a comma
- the replacement in `rest` of every comma with nothing

Comment: This was my first thought and is simple enough for the example but this is part of larger script where the array is massive and there's already loops and it would be a whole thing.  This would definitely work but would be very cumbersome to implement in the larger project I'm working on.

Comment: Fair enough; I just tried to answer within the limitations (parameter expansion only).