# Connection test for multiple host

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have simple script which show me if connection between server is working, problem is that now I have multiple number of servers which I want to check and I don't want to check one by one, would be good to add list of servers into file and script will be check each row in  file. Anyone can help to extend script with loop

```
    SERVER=$1
PORT=$2
nc -z -v -G5 $SERVER $PORT &> /dev/null
result1=$?


if [  "$result1" != 0 ]; then
  echo  port $PORT is closed on $SERVER
else
  echo port $PORT is open on $SERVER
fi
```

Comment: The best is to transform your variables into arrays link this : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508777/using-parameter-substitution-on-a-bash-array

Comment: Could be a good fit for `ansible` in ad-hoc mode

Comment: Are you wanting to check the same port or same list of ports on each server?  Or specific ports on specific servers?  It would help if you explained your use case a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

server.txt

```
[hostname or IP 1] [port 1]
[hostname or IP 2] [port 2]
[hostname or IP 3] [port 3]
[hostname or IP 4] [port 4]
[hostname or IP 5] [port 5]
```

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
while IFS=" " read -r SERVER PORT; do
  nc -z -v -G5 $SERVER $PORT &> /dev/null
  result1=$?

  if [  "$result1" != 0 ]; then
    echo "port $PORT is closed on $SERVER"
  else
    echo "port $PORT is open on $SERVER"
  fi
done < server.txt
```